# De bruijin sequence

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have the following statement -

**In every [De Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) over the alphabet {0,1} there is the same amount of  zeros and ones.**

I found it a little bit hard for proving ,if one can give some hints.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In a De Bruijn sequence of order $n$, every symbol is the last symbol of a unique length-$n$ substring, and conversely every possible length-$n$ string appears (by definition) exactly once -- in particular its last symbol will appear.

Thus, the number of zeroes in the De Bruijn sequence equals the number of $n$-symbol words that end with $0$ ...

Comment: Great hint, thank u.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as below.

Let's assume you have a DeBruijn sequence of order $n$. You can start from one end of the sequence and find the first sequence $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ of length $n$ and write its elements in a row. Then find the second sequence $a_2,a_3,...,a_{n+1}$ and write it in the second row. Continue this process until you have all $2^n$ sequences, in a column. It gives you a matrix $A$. You see that each column of $A$ has exactly the original DeBruijn sequence. Now, let's take one arbitrary column $j$ of $A$ and assume that we have more $1$ than $0$, in column $j$. Just consider rows that have their $j$ component equal to $1$. The rows are all different and there are $m>2^{n-1}$ of them. If you delete the component $j$ from all of them, they should still remain different. However, they are $m>2^{n-1}$ sequences of length $n-1$ and we can have at most $2^{n-1}$ different sequences of length $n-1$. Therefore two of the sequences are similar, which is a contradiction.